# Is there a way to remind the down-voter upon the related answer or quesion is changed?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

Down voting is a great way to discourage bad answers, but what if the original answer or question has been improved?

I believe providing a way to let the down-votes removable will highly encourage self-improving of answers and questions.

An idea after a quick discussion with @nohat:

> How about letting poster owner have the ability to send out the notifications to down voters, and holding a limitation like 10 notifications per user per day?

Comment: Future readers should eventually swamp downvotes that may no longer be unjustified. The best approach is to spend more time ensuring the original Q/A is as right as you can make it.

Answer (score 3):

Just two quick points.

1. If history is any lesson, people able to attract ten downvotes in a single day should be *prevented* from contacting people who spend their preciousss reps on keeping the site tidy. Seriously.
2. MSO:

   - [Allow an edit to notify downvoters: “I think I've fixed the issue now — please check”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-ch) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
   - [Feature request: @Downvoter sends a notification to all downvoters for your post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/feature-request-downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post) [status-huh-wha](/questions/tagged/status-huh-wha)

Comment: How'd you post the tag in that form? I'm curious.

Comment: @fireDude67: `[tag:status-declined]`.

Answer (score 1):

Downvotes **can** be reversed if a question in subsequently modified.

Comment: Are you saying a down vote will be reversed automatically if the question is subsequently modified in any way?

Comment: If a question is modified, then downvotes are "unlocked" and downvoters can cancel or reverse their vote.

Comment: I already noticed the unlock feature which is meaningful, but seems no notifications will be sent out to voters.

Comment: No, no notifications. I daresay people would do a lot less voting if they got notified every time something they voted on changed.

Comment: How about letting poster owner have the ability to send out the notifications to down voters, and holding a limitation like 10 notifications per user per day.

Comment: A very interesting idea! I suggest you make a separate request for that functionality, either here or at meta.stackoverflow.com